# How to insert inline PTX into OpenMP Code? Like we can do in CUDA code for Nvidia PTX Assembly?

Tags: cuda, openmp, nvidia, gpgpu, inline-assembly

I have an OpenMP code segment (parallel region). I want to add inline PTX assembly at the indicated line (shown below)
I am using **Nvidia gtx1070** gpu and ubuntu Linux and **clang** compiler. I tried `asm volatile()` method, but clang compiler throws compile error (shown below)

For example, If I call the following function warp_id() inside a CUDA kernel, we can extract the warp_id of the current thread execution:

```
__forceinline__ __device__ unsigned warp_id()
{
    unsigned ret; 
    asm volatile ("mov.u32 %0, %warpid;" : "=r"(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

I would like to do the same but inside an OpenMP parallel region.

```
#pragma omp target teams  distribute num_teams(15)
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
    { 
        #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) schedule(auto) 
        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {   
             // extract warpid of this current thread iteration 
        }
    }
```

### Clang Error:

```
"/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/ptxas" -m64 -O3 -v --gpu-name sm_61 --output-file /tmp/openmp_ptxasm-1fb0b2.cubin /tmp/openmp_ptxasm-07f1f7.s -c
ptxas info    : 59 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '__omp_offloading_817_6600b8_main_l32' for 'sm_61'
ptxas info    : Function properties for __omp_offloading_817_6600b8_main_l32
    56 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 72 registers, 416 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2]
ptxas info    : Function properties for _ZN27omptarget_nvptx_LoopSupportIllE13dispatch_nextEPiPlS2_S2_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
 "/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/nvlink" -o /tmp/openmp_ptxasm-0376ca.out -v -arch sm_61 -L. -L/home/mglab1/Desktop/llvm_new/install/lib -L/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64 -L/home/mglab1/Desktop/llvm_new/build/lib -lomptarget-nvptx /tmp/openmp_ptxasm-1fb0b2.cubin
nvlink info    : 703720068 bytes gmem
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__omp_offloading_817_6600b8_main_l32':
nvlink info    : used 72 registers, 56 stack, 1084 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2], 0 bytes lmem
 "/home/mglab1/Desktop/llvm_new/build/bin/clang-7" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name openmp_ptxasm.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /home/mglab1/Desktop/llvm_new/build/lib/clang/7.0.0 -O3 -Wall -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/mglab1/Codes/cuda -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -fopenmp -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/openmp_ptxasm-34c034.o -x ir /tmp/openmp_ptxasm-8ccc6a.bc -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -faddrsig
clang -cc1 version 7.0.0 based upon LLVM 7.0.0 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
<inline asm>:1:10: error: invalid register name
        mov.u32 %0, %smid;
                ^~
error: cannot compile inline asm
1 error generated.
```

This error was generated if I use inline PTX in the inner loop like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) schedule(auto) 
    for(int j = 0; j <C; j++)
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        unsigned int wid; 
        asm volatile("mov.u32 %0, %%warpid;" : "=r"(wid));
            printf("Iteration= c[ %d ][ %d ], Team=%d, Thread=%d, warp=%d\n",n, j, team_id, thread_id, wid);
        S[n][j] = A[n][j] * B[n][j];
    }
```

> Compile cmd: clang++ -fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda
>   -Xopenmp-target -march=sm_61 -Wall -O3 openmp.cpp

Comment: The error message isn't much help without the code which generated at. But the likelihood this can be made to work is extremely slim

Comment: Hi @talonmies, thanks a lot for looking into it. I've added the code for your clarification. So, you think it's not possible to embed inline ptx of Nvidia into OpenMP code?

Comment: As I wrote on your now deleted newer question, I don't believe this can work. nvcc and clang use different compilation trajectories, so the clang example blows up because of how it compiles code. And there isn't anything in the OpenMP standard which would allow you to "protect" a device code stanza and ensure it doesn't hit the host compiler. You might feasibly be able to do this in OpenACC, but not OpenMP as it is implemented in clang, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way that clang compiles code of this sort, and because neither clang nor OpenMP have any syntactic features that would allow the compiler to know that the `asm` should be treated as device code, I don't believe this can be made to work. There might be scope to do this using OpenACC, but not with OpenMP compiler driven accelerator offload.

[This answer assembled from comments and information added to another question which the OP deleted, and added as a community wiki entry to get it off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag. Feel free to edit and upvote as you see fit]